# trying to make tabbed uiwebview browser need help xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I am trying to make tab browser just like safari or chrome with tabs. 
when user open new url, webview will be added to array. and when user tap on button then openLoadedWebview: will called and remove the original webview and open a loaded webview from array.

**But it is not happening. things working are:**
webview removefromsuperview works.
wv succesfully added to self.view. with index number
**issue:**
new added wv is same as webview with same url.

any better idea or approach... I am totally new...

**mainViewController.h**

```
 @interface mainViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate>
    {
        UIWebView *webView;
        UIWebView *wv;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;
```

**mainViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 130, 300, 400);
    webView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {


    textField.text = [self repairURL:textField.text];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:textField.text];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [array addObject:webView];

    return true;
}

-(void)openLoadedWebview:(NSString *)pageLabel

    if ([cell.label.text isEqualToString:@"Trending"]) {
                NSLog(@"Selected Cell: %@", pageLabel);
            NSLog(@"number of objects %d", [array count]);
           // wv = [[UIWebView alloc]init];

            wv = [array objectAtIndex:0];
            wv.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 400);
            wv.delegate = self;
            [self.view addSubview:wv];


        }
      else if ([cell.label.text isEqualToString:@"Rec"]) {

            wv = [array objectAtIndex:1];
            wv.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 400);
            wv.delegate = self;
            [self.view addSubview:wv];
        }

[webView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of these:
https://github.com/graetzer/SGTabs
https://github.com/xxhp/BrowserTabViewDemo

I think this is what you are wanting to achieve: https://github.com/fictorial/BHTabBar

Comment: Thank you soo much It helped me alot... One more question how can I load/bring to front or remove any tab manually with code.? in SGTabs codes.

Comment: Also please tell me can I user SGTabs in my app? for free app or paid app?

Comment: Please refer to the README.md on the GitHub page for installation details